# How to fill gaps associating same value to specific factor? R

Tags: r

Assume I have a big data frame with 'Sample_n', 'Station', 'Lat' and 'Lon'.

Each station (from "1" to "100", for example) has a different amount of samples (random amount from 1 to 99, for example).

Although there are no gaps in 'Sample_n' and 'Station', 'Lat' and 'Lon' are full of NAs, but there is at least a full coordinate (lat+lon) for each station, placed at a random row.

I would like to fill the gaps of 'Lat' and 'Lon', associating the right values to the right station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample of your data would be of help. My best guess is that you can get what you want using the function `fill` from `tidyr` (also using functions in `dplyr` in the example):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(Sample_n=rep(1:3, each = 3), Station = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
             lat = c(NA, 50, NA, 40, NA, NA, NA, 55, NA),
             lon = c(NA, 150, NA, 140, NA, NA, NA, 155, NA))

df

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Sample_n Station   lat   lon
     <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1        1 a          NA    NA
2        1 a          50   150
3        1 a          NA    NA
4        2 b          40   140
5        2 b          NA    NA
6        2 b          NA    NA
7        3 c          NA    NA
8        3 c          55   155
9        3 c          NA    NA

df %>% group_by(Sample_n, Station) %>% 
  fill(lat, lon, .direction="updown")

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Sample_n, Station [3]
  Sample_n Station   lat   lon
     <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1        1 a          50   150
2        1 a          50   150
3        1 a          50   150
4        2 b          40   140
5        2 b          40   140
6        2 b          40   140
7        3 c          55   155
8        3 c          55   155
9        3 c          55   155
```